# Longest Common Subsequence Length function not returning the correct length?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have attempted to implement the dynamic programming approach to finding the longest common sub sequence between two sequences. My algorithm works when the two strings that are being compared are the same lengths, but when the second string is longer than the first, my `LCSLength()` function does not return the correct value.

Here is code with a test case that returns the wrong value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int LCSLength(string X,string Y);

int main()
{
    string first ("HELLO");
    string second ("HLOCKKE");
    int LCS;

    //ifstream inData;
    //inData.open("test.dat");

    //inData >> first >> second;
    //inData.close();

    LCS = LCSLength(first,second);
    cout << "The LCS is: " << LCS << endl;
    cout << first << endl;
    cout << second << endl;
    return 0;
}

int LCSLength(string X,string Y)
{
    int m = X.size();
    int n = Y.size();
    int C[m][n];
    for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
            C[i][j] = 0;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            if(X[i-1]==Y[j-1])
                C[i][j]=C[i-1][j-1]+1;
            else 
                C[i][j]=max(C[i][j-1],C[i-1][j]);
       }
    }

    return C[m][n];
}
```

This should print "The LCS is: 3" because the LCS between my two strings is 3, however, my program does not. I can't find my error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found one error - made the edit. Still not returning correct value.

Comment: what does it return? And why are you expecting `3`? I the longest common part I can see is `LO` which is `2`

Comment: I'm expecting `3` because the longest common subsequence is `HLO`. For this particular example, my program returns `4`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: I've tried the wiki's implementation already. Doesn't work for me. Maybe my indexing is off somewhere?

Comment: I don't see how your code supposed to work in the first place. You breach boundaries of your `C[m][n]` array which is an undefined behaviour

Comment: You're right. I found my remaining errors and posted the correct solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed my errors using some google searches. Indexing was my problem. Here is the correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int LCSLength(string X,string Y);

int main()
{
    string first ("HELLO");
    string second ("HLOCKKE");
    int LCS;

    //ifstream inData;
    //inData.open("test.dat");

    //inData >> first >> second;
    //inData.close();

    LCS = LCSLength(first,second);
    cout << "The LCS is: " << LCS << endl;
    cout << first << endl;
    cout << second << endl;
    return 0;
}

int LCSLength(string X,string Y)
{
    int m = X.size();
    int n = Y.size();
    int L[m+1][n+1];
    for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || j==0)
                L[i][j] = 0;
            else if(X[i-1]==Y[j-1])
                L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1]+1;
            else
                L[i][j] = max(L[i-1][j],L[i][j-1]);
        }
    }
    return L[m][n];
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around: your `for` loops should iterate while `i<m` and `j<n` (not "smaller or equal to"). In most C-like languages, arrays are 0-based, meaning that an array of `n` items has indices from `0` to `n-1`, inclusive.